# Matplotlib candlestick TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, matplotlib, quantitative-finance

I have a **`Dataframe`** in the format as follows:

```
    Date    Open    Close    High    Low    Volume
1   float   float   float    float   float  int64
2   ...
3   ...
```

The `Date` is in `float` days format and everything else (except `Volume`) is a `float` as confirmed by `df.types`.

I passed this `Dataframe` to a **`matplotlib`** `.candlestick_ochl()` method, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.finance as mf

mf.candlestick_ochl(ax, df)
```

The return is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'` which makes me feel like I'm somehow getting an error that `candlestick_ochl()` is trying to subtract two strings, but where?

> **In the traceback**
>  the error arises from line 788 in finance.py _candlestick:  `height = close - open`

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html#matplotlib.finance.candlestick_ochl  The documentation expects a row-wise iterable.  If you iterate over a dataframe you get the column names.

Comment: @tcaswell Good call. I guess I didn't quite realize that from the documentation when I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per [**tcaswell**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell)'s note I simply added the following changes:

```
MOCHLV = zip(df.Date, df.Open, df.Close, df.High, df.Low, df.Volume)

mf.candestick_ochl(ax, MOCHLV)
```